# join f1 to f2 so that each join-able f1 record only joins once to the first available match-able in f2

Tags: awk, sed, join

Given the following two files which are sorted by column 1 and 2:

f1:

```
card1,value1,f1c11,f1c12
card2,value2,f1c21,f1c22
card3,value3,f1c31,f1c32
card4,value4,f1c41,f1c42
card4,value4,f1c411,f1c412
card4,value41,f1c421,f1c422
card5,vaule5,f1c51,f1c52
```

f2:

```
card,value2,f2c1,f2c2
card2,value,f2c21,f2c22
card2,value2,f2c211,f2c212
card2,value2,f2c221,f2c222
card3,value3,f2c31,f2c32
card4,value4,f2c41,f2c42
card4,value4,f2c411,f2c412
card5,vaule5,f2c51,f2c52
card6,vaule6,f2c61,f2c62
card7,vaule5,f2c71,f2c72
```

Desired: Join f1 to f2 so that each join-able f1 record only joins once to the first available match-able in f2:

```
card2,value2,f1c21,f1c22,f2c211,f2c212
card3,value3,f1c31,f1c32,f2c31,f2c32
card4,value4,f1c41,f1c42,f2c41,f2c42
card4,value4,f1c411,f1c412,f2c41,f2c42
card5,vaule5,f1c51,f1c52,f2c51,f2c52
```

Here is the detail matching logic:

- card1,value1 in f1 (row 1) does not see any match in f2 -> ignore
- card2,value2 in f1 (row 2) sees the first match in f2 (row 3), after this match, f1 row 2 and f2 row 3 are no longer available -> card2,value2,f1c21,f1c22,f2c211,f2c212
- card3,value3 in f1 (row 3) sees the first match in f2 (row 5), after this match, f1 row 3 and f2 row 5 are no longer available -> card3,value3,f1c31,f1c32,f2c31,f2c32
- card4,value4 in f1 (row 4) sees the first match in f2 (row 6), after this match, f1 row 4 and f2 row 6 are no longer available -> card4,value4,f1c41,f1c42,f2c41,f2c42
- card4,value4 in f1 (row 5) sees the first match in f2 (row 7), after this match, f1 row 5 and f2 row 7 are no longer available -> card4,value4,f1c411,f1c412,f2c41,f2c42
- card4,value4 in f1 (row 6) does not see any match in f2 -> ignore
- card5,value5 in f1 (row 7) sees the first match in f2 (row 8), after this match, f1 row 7 and f2 row 8 are no longer available -> card5,vaule5,f1c51,f1c52,f2c51,f2c52

Comment: So the match key is the concatenation of the first two fields? And the files are not sorted in key order? That is, does "first available" mean "lowest key" or "earliest in file as received" ?

Comment: Yes, sorry to mention, the the keys are colunm1 and 2. Files are sorted. "Available" means if the record  was successfully joined before than then it is no longer available to join.

Comment: Why are there two `card4,value4` in your desired output?

Comment: @Cyrus, there are 3 card4,value4 in file 1 and there is only 2 in file 2 so only the first 2 records can join. The last record card4,value4 in file 1 no longer has any "available" record in file 2 to join

Answer (score 0):

Scripted in Bash and GNU awk. This does not require either input file to be sorted: the output is in the order of the first file passed as an argument.

I think your fourth output line is in error: it repeats the f2 card4 first row again.

The whole of the second file is saved in an array Row, with the row numbers held as a list in Map in input sequence.

The first file then removes any map entry it uses, until none remains.

```
#! /bin/bash --

#:: firstJoin: join only the first records with matching keys.

Join () {

    local AWK='
BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS = ","; reClip = "^[^,]*,[^,]*,"; }
#.. Store input from first file.
function Store (key, tx, Local) {
    sub (reClip, "", tx);
    Row[FNR] = tx;
    Map[key] = Map[key] FNR FS FS;
}
#.. Pair second file with first available.
function Pair (key, tx, Local) {
    if (! (key in Map) || (Map[key] == "")) return;
    printf ("%s%s%s\n", tx, OFS, Row[0+Map[key]]);
    sub (reClip, "", Map[key]);
}
FNR == NR { Store( $1 FS $2, $0); next; }
{ Pair( $1 FS $2, $0); }
'   
    awk -f <( printf '%s' "${AWK}" ) "${2}" "${1}"
}   
    
    Join "${1}" "${2}"
```

Test shot:

```
Paul--) ./firstJoin  JoinF1 JoinF2
card2,value2,f1c21,f1c22,f2c211,f2c212
card3,value3,f1c31,f1c32,f2c31,f2c32
card4,value4,f1c41,f1c42,f2c41,f2c42
card4,value4,f1c411,f1c412,f2c411,f2c412
card5,vaule5,f1c51,f1c52,f2c51,f2c52
Paul--)
```